# ¿Cómo instalo tkinter en Python 3?

Tags: python

Cuando intento importar `tkinter` desde *Python*, exactamente la *versión 3.6.9*, veo el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tkinter está disponible en la práctica totalidad de los repositorios oficiales de casi todas las distribucioes Linux. Así que, para instalarlo, dependiendo de que distribución uses, desde la terminal ejecuta:

#### Basadas en Debian (Ubuntu, LinuxMint, etc):

```
sudo apt install python3-tk
```

#### Basadas en RHEL (Fedora, CentOS, etc)

```
sudo dnf install python3-tkinter
```

#### Basadas en OpenSuse:

```
sudo zypper in python3-tk
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que para hacer lo que estas pidiendo, necesitas ejecutar el siguiente comando ya que el paquete **tkinter** no existe por lo visto

`pip install tk-tools`